# Web scraping DEEPL.com using VBA Excel and Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, deepl

i'm trying to code a function to translate sentences in Excel using DEEPL.com
My approach is using Selenium to scrape the web using Chrome (as IExplore is not supported by the web).

```
Public Function deepL(txt As String, inputLang As String, outputLang As String)
Dim url As String
Dim driver As New WebDriver

url = "https://www.deepl.com/translator#" & inputLang & "/" & outputLang & "/" & txt
driver.Start "Chrome"
driver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 5000
driver.Get url

deepL = driver.FindElementById("target-dummydiv").Text
driver.Close

End Function
----
Sub translating()
'test for word "probando" from "es" to "en"
'url: https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/probando
'it should return: "testing"
MsgBox (deepL("probando", "es", "en"))
End Sub
```

The problem comes when loading the web, so the div containing the translation is empty on load, and the GET instruction returns an empty text.
But after 1 second, the page refreshes with the correct result:

```
<div id="target-dummydiv" aria-hidden="true" class="lmt__textarea lmt__textarea_dummydiv" lang="en-US">testing</div>
```

I tried adding an implicit wait of 5 seconds in order to give time to the webpage to load, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I found that the div with the translation has visibility: hidden. If I show the visibility, the results are correct, but don't know how to get that in my code

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Sending the text, selecting `en` or scraping the result?

Comment: scraping the result.
When running the code, it returns always "", but if I pause the code after the GET and change visibility of the div containing the data I want to scrape, then it returns correctly "testing"

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution:

just select the textarea where the translation is located and get the translation with .attribute("value") instead of .text

```
deepL = driver.FindElementByCss("textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style").Attribute("value")
```

Comment: Ever thought of using the API directly instead of weird scraping? :)
https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api

Comment: hello, yes. I'm using the API, but this was just a test, and a solution in case API fails. Thx!

Comment: @Gustavo Rodriguez Coronas hice la solucion que propones en tu post, un asi el resultados me da "vacio"